# When evaluating a case for Pi with an upper-hat, are all upper-hats the same dimensions?

Tags: hat, case, pi-5

I'm looking at getting a [Pineberry HatDrive! Top](https://pineberrypi.com/products/hat-top-2230-2240-for-rpi5). This is a hat that fits on top of the Raspberry Pi 5. Does this fit in any case that fits a Raspberry Pi with hat?

It seems unlike the PineBerry lower hat, the HatDrive! Top mirroring a regular Pi-5 hat is a bit more common. I'm hoping this makes finding a case easier.